# Structure of Br3O8

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, radicals

What is the structure of $\ce{Br3O8}$? It has an odd number of electrons; does that make it a free radical?

The structure given in my book shows

[image]

Where did the 7th electron of the central atom go?

---

Picture from book (Pg 265, NCERT Chemistry Part II, class 11):

[image: Pic from book]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The electron didn't go anywhere. It's in an unhybridized p orbital on the central bromine, and yes, $\ce{Br3O8}$ is a free radical. That is why it decomposes above -80ºC.$^{[1]}$

---

<sub>$^{[1]}$ Cotton, F. A. Progress in Inorganic Chemistry - Volume 2; Interscience Publishers: New York, NY, 1960.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies everything. Isn't it mandatory to mention a free radical to be so in the bond structure?

Comment: Yes, @ghosts. If the structure drawing in your book doesn't indicate in some way that there is a free radical, then it is very likely a misprint. Look closely and make sure there isn't a dot somewhere around the Br atom!

Comment: @CodyGray The asterisk has a different meaning indicated in the text. So no dot then :P

Comment: Well, now that you've shown us the picture, I can see that it *does* give the oxidation states for the bromines. So this is not a misprint, the data is there, you just have to understand it. If this is a textbook, though, I would say that it could be substantially improved by not expecting the student to understand how atomic oxidation states work and *explicitly* indicating that there is a free radical.

Comment: I see a number of basic copyediting errors in the text surrounding the structures - I think this is not a very good textbook.

Comment: @zwol There are many questions and answers on our site that use NCERT texts. I find them insufficient and outdated at best, sometimes they are even outrageously wrong; it often looks like they have been effortlessly copy & pasted together from already bad sources.