Can methyl shift occur for isobutyl cation?
I had a problem on Markovnikov addition in my school chemistry class and was wondering is this step possible in the carbocation intermediate because from what I understand methyl shift can happen between branched methyl chains?


If you were to do a methyl shift, you would be going from the secondary carbocation to a primary one. I don’t think so.

But the migratory aptitude of Hydrogen is better than Alkyl. Anyways I have seen this rearrangement only while Friedel Crafts alkylation

Sec-butyl cation maybe? Isobutyl would have the branched methyl group already and thus would merely undergo hydride shifting.

A simple methyl shift will not get you from secondary to tertiary butyl cation. You need to combine it with a hydride shift in the opposite direction. The hydride shift is necessary because you need to convert a methylene carbon in the middle of the butyl chain to a methyl group in the branched tert-butyl structure.
Yet this reaction does occur and you have to chill the reaction mixture to suppress it. For instance, the enthalpy change associated with this rearrangement has been measured in $\ce{SO2ClF}$ that has been chilled below -100°C and is warmed in a +25°C bath to set off the reaction[1].
Reference

E. W. Bittner, E. M. Arnett, M. Saunders. "Quantitative preparation and enthalpy of rearrangement of the sec-butyl cation". J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1976, 98, 12, 3734–3735. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00428a072.


Carbocation rearrangements only take place when there is stability involved in every step/rearrangement
In your diagram , when you do methyl shift , then the resulting carbocation is less stable compared to the original carbocation
From 5 alpha H , the new carbocation will only be stabilised by 1 alpha H... therefore this step will never take place.


You know better then guys who wrote a paper about it?

@Mithoron but don't you think it is the same thing written in the comments? Are you referring to the paper in the above answer? Maybe there would have been some discussion herein before I popped up but your tone seems criticizing?

@Mithoron I have been taught this concept in my class by my professor, and it really helps in ruling out several possibilities of carbocation rearrangements. Just like above they mentioned about primary/secondary carbocation , similarly I thought I would add whatever I have learnt

@Mithoron Not everyone would pass your level of understanding, so you should help the users by providing your reasoning instead of providing a snarky comment even it was meant a criticism. Our role model should be to kind with fellow users.

I think it's pretty clear that Oscar says the rearrangement does happen, and has a paper to back this up. What does an answer with opposite statement say, then?

@Mithoron oh it is a no hate comment, but as Adhway noted, this is the way we are taught in indian coaching centres, this is the way I learnt and this is the way most kids learn here.....

So the indian coaching centres need to update their concepts. It's not your fault but you will realize that people here really do not like the concepts Indian textbooks and the teaching staff preach here. @CuckooBeats

See Martin's comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/68458/17368

@NilayGhosh :O i had heard of such criticisms, didnt believe they were that real, i meant smth different but oh well

Yikes! So much for DEI! This is sad, actually, given India's history in math and science.
